# DocuSign JWT Invalid Access Token

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, jwt, docusignapi

I have upgraded the DocuSign eSign NuGet package from 4.1.1 to the latest version 5.1.0 in my test project.

Test Code:

```
            var auth = DocuSign.eSignature.JWTAuth.AuthenticateWithJWT();
            string accessToken = auth.accessToken;
            string accountId = auth.accountId;
            string basePath = auth.baseUri;

            var config = new Configuration(basePath);
            config.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

            EnvelopeDefinition envelope = MakeEnvelope("user@somecompany.com", "User Name", "",
                "", "15ffda8-5953-4e5f-b9d6-112133adf0e7");

            var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(new ApiClient(config));
            EnvelopeSummary result = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
```

However, since then I am receiving the following error when running the code:

DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: 'Error calling CreateEnvelope: {"errorCode":"USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED","message":"One or both of Username and Password are invalid. Invalid access token"}'

I got the AuthenticateWithJWT() method from DocuSign:

```
        public static (string accessToken, string accountId, string baseUri) AuthenticateWithJWT()
        {
            var apiClient = new ApiClient();
            string ik = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IntegrationKey"];
            string userId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userId"];
            string authServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthServer"];
            string rsaKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RSAKey"];
            OAuth.OAuthToken authToken = apiClient.RequestJWTUserToken(ik,
                            userId,
                            authServer,
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rsaKey),
                            1);

            string accessToken = authToken.access_token;
            apiClient.SetOAuthBasePath(authServer);
            OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.GetUserInfo(authToken.access_token);
            Account acct = null;

            var accounts = userInfo.Accounts;
            {
                acct = accounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IsDefault == "true");
            }
            string accountId = acct.AccountId;
            string baseUri = acct.BaseUri + "/restapi";
            return (accessToken, accountId, baseUri);
        }
```

It is correctly returning my accountId, an access token, and a base path just like before.
Any ideas on what might be causing this error or what steps I might take to troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to put together a solution for this:

```
            var auth = DocuSign.eSignature.JWTAuth.AuthenticateWithJWT();
            string accessToken = auth.accessToken;
            string accountId = auth.accountId;
            string basePath = auth.baseUri;

            var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
            apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

            EnvelopeDefinition envelope = MakeEnvelope("user@somecompany.com", "User Name", "",
                "", "15ffda8-5953-4e5f-b9d6-112133adf0e7");

            var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
            EnvelopeSummary result = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
```

You no longer have to create a separate Configuration object.
You can pass the basePath directly into the ApiClient constructor.
The new apiClient instance has a Configuration property on it where you can set the DefaultHeader with your accessToken information. Finally you can pass the configured apiClient instance into the EnvelopesApi constructor.

Answer (score 0):

might mean you're hitting the wrong environment (i.e. a Prod Key against a Demo endpoint or a Demo Key against a Prod endpoint). so make sure the baseUri is correct for the access token/key you're using